Scheduler values are auto populating on content submission
When i save the content with some required field empty it states the server side validation error message. Also it is filling the scheduler "Publish on" and "unpublish on" date. It is taking the date and time when i did the submission and when i try to submit again by providing the required field it is stating error "The 'unpublish on' date must be in the future."

After updating the mandatory field it is again showing me the error on the "Unpublish on" as shown below:


Submitted as a bug: https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler/issues/3475483
